# How do we set a Limit on a Collection?

Tags: collection-filtering

The answers that I found on Google was only available for the Catalog with a `setPage($pageNum, $pageSize)`.

That didn't work on any other collections.

Any help Will be Appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes I found the Solution.

Just we have to add one line after Fetch Collection.

```
$collection->getSelect()->limit(1);
```

Thanks to [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322333/magento-set-limit-on-collection)

Answer (score 3):

For other types of collections you can do something similar but the code is broken down in 2 methods.

```
$collection->setPageSize($pageSize)->setCurPage($currentPage);
```